# Как получить из базы время в чужой таймзоне?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, timestamp

Задача — отслеживание пользователей из разных таймзон на карте. При клике на маячки должно показываться локальное время того пользователя, чей маячок.

Пользователь приезжает в контрольную точку скажем в Хабаровске в семь утра, жмет кнопку "приехал". На сервер улетают его координаты и его локальное время (`Date.now()` из `js`, если имеет значение).

На сервере `mysql`, формат хранения `datetime`. Можно переделать таблицу как угодно, заказчик ругаться не будет.

Наблюдатель из Москвы видит маячок на карте Хабаровска, кликает на него и получает — пользователь был здесь в 12 ночи по Москве.

Вроде бы все логично, но наблюдателю нужно знать, во сколько пользователь был на точке в Хабаровске именно по хабаровскому времени. Наблюдатель не хочет постоянно пересчитывать время, тем более что пользователей десятка два, и все они в разных таймзонах.

Как бы показать ему правильное время? 
Спасибо.

Comment: в каком виде время уходит на сервер?

Answer (score 1):

При наличии таймзон стандартное решение - хранить время по Гринвичу. При любом другом решении придётся объяснять всем, какое там время и почему это хорошо.

Comment: судя по всему оно так и хранится, просто при выводе выводится как есть, а яваскрипт по умолчанию выводит в текущей таймзоне

Comment: Таймзону должен выбирать юзер

Comment: Не понял комментарий

Comment: Кнопка должна быть.

Comment: Все равно не понял, как это к моему комментарию о том что, просто выводится дата, и по умолчанию яваскрипт toString выводит именно в формате текущей таймзоны, относится :-)

Answer (score 0):

Определяйте геокоординаты сотрудника, заносите их в бд вместе с его локальным временем. Зная координаты, можно без труда автоматически вычислить время.